# Unable to load DLL 'EDSDK.dll' Canon SDK Error in C#

Tags: c#, canon-sdk

I'm trying to add to an existing website using the Canon SDK and it's resize options. I have added the EDSDK.cs to my App_Code folder and these dlls to my Bin directory: EdsImage.dll, EDSDK.dll, MLib.dll, Ucs32P.dll, DPPDLL.dll, DPPLibCom.dll, and DPPRSC.dll. My code is just trying to convert the image to a JPG file:

```
uint err;
        err = EDSDK.EdsInitializeSDK();
        IntPtr inStream;
        err = EDSDK.EdsCreateFileStream("img_001.CR2", EDSDK.EdsFileCreateDisposition.OpenExisting, EDSDK.EdsAccess.Read, out inStream);
        IntPtr imgRef;
        err = EDSDK.EdsCreateImageRef(inStream, out imgRef);
        err = EDSDK.EdsSetPropertyData(imgRef, EDSDK.PropID_WhiteBalance, 0, 4, EDSDK.WhiteBalance_Cloudy);
        IntPtr outStream;
        err = EDSDK.EdsCreateFileStream("img_001.jpg", EDSDK.EdsFileCreateDisposition.CreateAlways, EDSDK.EdsAccess.Write, out outStream);
        EDSDK.EdsImageInfo info;
        err = EDSDK.EdsGetImageInfo(imgRef, EDSDK.EdsImageSource.FullView, out info);
        EDSDK.EdsSaveImageSetting set = new EDSDK.EdsSaveImageSetting();
        set.JPEGQuality = 9;
        err = EDSDK.EdsSaveImage(imgRef, EDSDK.EdsTargetImageType.Jpeg, set, outStream);
        EDSDK.EdsRelease(imgRef);
        EDSDK.EdsRelease(inStream);
        EDSDK.EdsRelease(outStream);
        EDSDK.EdsTerminateSDK();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: Could you please add what kind of error you get? is err != OK or do you get an exception?

Comment: Unable to load DLL 'EDSDK.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) the error is happening at the line err = EDSDK.EdsInitializeSDK();

Comment: So the exception is of type DllNotFoundException, right? Considering that this is a website, the actual execution probably does not take place in the bin folder. That may be why they're not found. To try that, replace the path "EDSDK.dll" of this [DllImport("EDSDK.dll")] (in EDSDK.cs) with an absolute path of where the DLL is. e.g. [DllImport("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\yourwebsite\bin\EDSDK.dll")]

Comment: i will give that a shot. Thanks.

Comment: That seems to load the dll, but it is now returning an error: err = EDSDK.EdsInitializeSDK();
    if(err == EDSDK.EDS_ERR_OK) 
    {
     Trace.Warn("Success");
    } else
    {
    Trace.Warn("Error");
    }

Comment: again, please post the actual error (value of err). your error checking code is no use.

Comment: EDS_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR

Comment: that might be a problem... This error means something went wrong within the SDK but we can't know what. My guess is that it's some sort of right/access problem related to your project being a website. I'm afraid I can't help you further with that, sorry. Alternatively you could try running this code in a normal application and see if it fails there too. If so, the problem must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this problem that I wanted to share in case anyone had the same problem. I downloaded a .exe file here http://www.centrostudiprogressofotografico.it/en/dcraw/ and ran it as a process in the website to convert the .cr2 to a jpg. Here is the code:

```
string dcRawExe = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("PATH TO:/dcraw-9.26-ms-64-bit.exe");
string strCR2File = "PATH TO CR2 FILE";
string strJPGFile = "PATH TO JPG FILE";
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(dcRawExe)
{
    Arguments = "-c -e \"" + strCR2File + "\"",
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
};
var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(process.StandardOutput.BaseStream);
image.Save(strJPGFile, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```